# AccessViolationException on a deleted array

Tags: visual-c++, access-violation

```
static void InvShiftRows(BYTE* dest)
{
    tcout << "\t\t\tInvShiftRows()+" << EOL;
    BYTE* temp = new BYTE[16];
    ByteUtil::LogArray("temp1", temp, 16);
    memcpy(temp, dest, 16);
    ByteUtil::LogArray("temp2", temp, 16);
    dest[0x01] = temp[0x0D];
    dest[0x02] = temp[0x0A];
    dest[0x03] = temp[0x07];
    dest[0x05] = temp[0x01];
    dest[0x06] = temp[0x0E];
    dest[0x07] = temp[0x0B];
    dest[0x09] = temp[0x05];
    dest[0x0A] = temp[0x02];
    dest[0x0B] = temp[0x0F];
    dest[0x0D] = temp[0x09];
    dest[0x0E] = temp[0x06];
    dest[0x0F] = temp[0x03];
    ByteUtil::LogArray("Dest1", dest, 16);
    delete[] temp;
    tcout << "\t\t\tInvShiftRows()-" << EOL;
}
```

So i've traced down that the access violation happens occasionally on the `delete[] temp` and for the life of me i can not figure out why. It only does it randomly. Any clue as to why?

**EDIT**
per request to see ByteUtil::LogArray

```
void ByteUtil::LogArray(char* header, const BYTE* thearray, int length)
{
    tcout << header << "(" << length << ")-";

    char* number = new char[4];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        sprintf_s(number, 4,"%02X:", thearray[i]);
        wcout << number;
    }
    delete[] number;
    wcout << EOL; //EOL is just std::endl << std::flush
}
```

honestly i think I made a few bad moves with delete[]. I learned in one of my code review posts that I should use delete[] whenever I use new X[] so I started putting them everywhere that I had something like `BYTE temp[4]` i would replace with `BYTE* temp = new BYTE[4]` and add a corresponding delete[]. and at first it appeared that if i used new X[] that it would set all the values in that array to zero (turned out to be bogus, as it was throwing off my encrypt/decrypt methods) So now I'm trying to figure out which one of my deletes is deleting too much... which makes me want to ask another question..

is it irresponsible to have `BYTE temp[4] = {0x00};` in a method? or is it better practice to use `new X[]` and `delete[]`?

Comment: The memory is _already_ corrupted at the point of deletion. You should look for the problem in a different place.

Comment: yeah...trying to find that has been a thorn in my flesh. That would explain why it is random.. Sometimes it was this function, sometimes other functions... and never in the same spot... This is really driving me bonkers...

Comment: is it possible that ByteUtil::LogArray is doing this? Can you show us its code?

Comment: I will show it in a second.. I will admit though that it appears to be somewhere else... and i can't figure it out.. I really need to spend some time on pointers and learn them better, but unfortunatly this particular project is on a time schedule. :/ and this bit of code isn't always the culprit.. seems to be anywhere that has the delete[] method. ugh..

Comment: @Robert Snyder BYTE temp[4] = {0x00} is ok. The better practice might be using std::vector or std::array.

Comment: @GrigoriyChudnov Well i turned on Set Debug Flag, but i found a great article on using std::array/std::vector.. I'm going to try to put in a few of those later today instead of what i have since it appears to be cleaner, and I don't have to call delete :) Time to check my debugger

Comment: hahahah, my program didn't get get a chance to turn on completly before it through an assertion error.. Guess that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is related to the heap corruption, you can include `<crtdbg.h>`
and turn ON heap checks for every alloc/dealloc:

Run somewhere at the beginning of the app:

```
// _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF -- Turn on debug allocation
// _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF -- check the heap's integrity at every allocation and deallocation.
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF);
```

If the problem is heap-related, you'll get an assertion (Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _CrtCheckMemory()). After this point trace back the program execution and look for the place where the heap is corrupted.

E.g. if you add `dest[0x10] = temp[0x03];` to your code above and *dest* was allocated on the heap, you'll get an assertion inside LogArray on cout.

**NOTE:** setting _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF could make your app run slow.

Comment: this is why i love this place.. Thank you for suggestion. I can't wait to try it out. I don't mind it being slow, as long as I can trace it down and find it.. It is so frustrating to have your program crash 100 times to get it work once... This maybe a dumb question but does my build have to be in debug mode?

Comment: @Robert Snyder yes, when _DEBUG is not defined, calls to _CrtSetDbgFlag are removed during preprocessing.

Comment: This my friend my be a perfect solution than because my release can not be the debug build. HA! Thank you.. This morning I decided to see if I could get rid of my problem by getting rid of all delete[] and it seems to have slowed it down...which means to me that i am using more than I am allocating, now to turn on this debug trick and check it out. Will it hurt that project is a COM library for OPOS?

Comment: @Robert Snyder _CrtSetDbgFlag should not be used in production. It is great for debugging purposes. Yeah, it might be better to use std::vector or std::array instead of new[] and delete[]. I don't know the requirements, but there should be no problems when using std::vector in a COM library for OPOS.